# How can i put an exception on EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION?

Tags: swift, exception

I'm trying to put an exception for the following line:

```
let someData Int = Int(anArray[0])!
```

I want the exception so that it ignores it if its a string instead of an integer.

Im new to swift, but in python i could just do the following:

```
try:
    let someData Int = Int(anArray[0])!
except:
    pass
```

I've tried the following:

```
guard let someData Int = Int(anArray[0])! else {
    print("error")
}
```

,

```
let someData Int = try! Int(anArray[0])!
```

I'm using swift 3

Comment: In Swift to *put an exception for* creating an `Int` from a `String` is called Optional Binding described in [Swift Language Guide: The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the proper solution:

```
if let someData = Int(anArray[0]) {
    // someData is a valid Int
}
```

Or you can use `guard`:

```
guard let someData = Int(anArray[0]) else {
    return // not valid
}

// Use someData here
```

Note the complete lack of the use of `!`. Don't force-unwrap optionals unless you know it can't fail.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, try-catch blocks look like this:

```
do {
    //call a throwable function, such as 
    try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data)
} catch {
    //handle error
}
```

However, you can only catch errors from **throwable** functions, which are always marked with the **throws** keyword in the documentation. The try keyword can only be used on throwable functions and do-catch blocks only have an effect when you use the try keyword inside the do block.

You cannot catch other types of exceptions, such as force casting/unwrapping exception that you are trying to catch.

The proper way of handling Optional values if to use optional binding.

```
guard let someData = Int(anArray[0]) else {
    print("error")
    return //bear in mind that the else of a guard statement has to exit the scope
}
```

If you don't want to exit the scope:

```
if let someData = Int(anArray[0]) {
    //use the integer
} else {
    //not an integer, handle the issue gracefully
}
```